# Syntax Errors when creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When I try to create the store procedure with following code, I am getting errors.

```
     create procedure Currentmonth(
       @Completeddatekey varchar(20) )
      as
        begin
```

Getting the current date and formatting it

```
          Declare @currentdate varchar(30)
         set @currentdate = convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)
            print @currentdate
```

Getting DayofMonth and EndofMonth from DimDate

```
      Declare @dayofmonth int
       Declare @endofmonth varchar(20)
      select @dayofmonth = DayofMonth, @endofmonth = EndofMonthDateKey from DimDate
      where datekey = @currentdate
```

Getting HierMonthEndKey

```
      declare @hiermonthendkey int
       select @hiermonthendkey = MAX(HierMonthEndKey) from DimHospiceHiearchy
         where HierMonthEndKey <= @currentdate+1
```

Declare @day

For Loop

```
      Declare @i int = 0
       declare @startdate varchar(20)
      select @startdate = CAST(CAST(YEAR(convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)) AS     VARCHAR(4)) 
     + '/' + CAST(MONTH(convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01'  AS DATETIME)+1

      While @i <=@dayofmonth
       (

         set @startdate = @startdate+@i
       Call MA010103(@completeddatekey,@hiermonthendkey)
        set @i = @i+1
       )

         end
```

I am getting these errors when I try to create the above store procedure

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Currentmonth, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Currentmonth, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near 'Call'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Currentmonth, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHILE` loop should look like that:

```
While @i <=@dayofmonth
begin
    set @startdate = @startdate+@i
    exec MA010103 @completeddatekey, @hiermonthendkey 
    set @i = @i+1
end
```

1. You need to use `BEGIN` and `END`, not brackets.
2. To execute a stored proc, use `EXECUTE` (or `EXEC`) and do not use parenthesis for parameters.